# How would I find a point on the y-axis equidistant from two other points?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The points are$$(5,-5) and (1,1)$$

I tried doing this visually and came up with (0,-5). This wasn't correct once I applied the distance formula to check the distance between that point and the two others.

Comment: Let the point be $(0,y)$. Then $5^2+(y+5)^2=1^2+(y-1)^2$. Expand and solve. (There are other ways.)

Comment: As for what you did wrong, I'm not sure, but $(-5,0)$ is not on the $y$-axis...

Comment: that was a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A point on the $y-$axis is of the form $(0,y)$.

The distance between $(0,y)$ and $(5,-5)$ is:
$$\sqrt{(5-0)^2+(-5-y)^2}=\sqrt{25+(5+y)^2}$$

The distance between $(0,y)$ and $(1,1)$ is:
$$\sqrt{(1-0)^2+(1-y)^2}=\sqrt{1+(1-y)^2}$$

The two distances are equal, so also their squares:

$$25+(5+y)^2=1+(1-y)^2$$

Now you have to solve for $y$.

Comment: It's probably more convenient to equate the squares of the distances, rather than the distances themselves.

Comment: I have doubts but I think it's (0,-4)

Comment: It is correct!!

Answer (score 10):

You want the point where the perpendicular bisector of the two points cuts the $y$-axis.

[image]

The slope of the line between $(5,-5)$ and $(1,1)$ is $-\frac{3}{2}$, so the slope of the normal is $\frac23$. Hence the normal through the mid-point $(3,-2)$ cuts the $y$-axis at $(0,-4)$.

Comment: +1 because on seeing the question I thought to myself, "well personally I'd just solve the equation, but what would *that* teach you about the set of points equidistant between A and B?" :-)

Comment: @Steve: Yes! I was disturbed by all those quadratic terms in the other answers, which always cancelled each other out.

Comment: That's an insight in itself, mind you. They cancel out *so that the set of equidistant points can be a straight line*, as opposed to something curved if there were quadratic terms left in there!

Comment: This also illustrates why it's always possible to find such a point, unless the given points lie on a horizontal line (which would make the perpendicular bisector parallel to the $y$-axis.